# Is it possible to send Shared Drive's login information via Scheduled Task Arguments?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I have an application stored in a shared drive that requires user and password to login and access its files. I also have a scheduled task that is supposed to run that application on a local pc.

Is it possible to use the scheduled task's arguments to send the login data the drive needs in order to find and execute the application?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this using Batch is probably to just map a drive for the logged in user using the correct credentials, and save that (reconnect at login). Then you can call the program using something like Z:\app.exe without having to store your creds in plaintext. Alternatively you can use the `NET USE` command to pass credentials.

Using PowerShell, you can just `cd \\server\share\` to the remote directory and run your application. Make sure you set the scheduled task to run as the correct user in the 'Create Task' wizard.